# Center text in link which is as block

Tags: html, css

Ill start with showing you my problem in an image:
[image]

So i want to make a design for slider, now i want to make buttons for next and previous.
yellow things in image are links with display: block. What do i need to do, to make text ( those arrows are unicode characters ) be positioned vertically and horizontally? Considering i still want whole yellow thing be clickable as a link.
here is how yellow thing looks in css

```
    a.prev {
width: 40px;
height: 270px;
display:block;
float:left;
background: yellow;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 55px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 55px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 45px;
```

}

Comment: Vertically aligning (for different heights) can be done with jQuery. Would you want that?

Comment: Im fine now, but you could post code, maybe it will be useful for someone else :)

Comment: Done. :) Hope it's good for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Since you have a fixed height you can use a top margin to push your arrows down to the vertical center</s>.

`text-align:center` should center your arrow horizontally.

Set `line-height` equal to the `height` of the element to center vertically.

Comment: Thought, maybe there is one dynamic method that would do it. So it would work for any heights. margin-top pushes whole element down. Padding-top works, but then i need to substract that value from height, so it lines up with rest of stuff.

Comment: Actually what might be a better fit is `line-height`.  Try setting `line-height` equal to the height of the element.

Answer (score 1):

I know an answer was accepted already, but I am just giving an alternative and a method that should work on dynamic heights.

I was not sure whether the arrows were merely inside an a `<a href=#">&larr;</a>` or inside a span `<a href=#"><span>&larr;</span></a>`. When they are not inside a span, it should be added with jQuery.

Static width and height: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N75qy/1).

```
// Add span-wrappers around controls
$("a.controls").each(function() {
    $(this.firstChild).wrap("<span></span>");
});

// Position arrows vertically
$("a.controls > span").css("top", function() {
    var thisH = $(this).height(),
        parentH = $(this).parent().height(),
        thisTop = (parentH/2) - (thisH/2);
    return thisTop;
});
```

Now, when you are using a dynamic/fluid lay-out this will not work well because the top-value is only calculated once. We need to recalculate the value every time the window is resized. Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N75qy/2/).

```
// Keep aspect ratio of div
function slideHeight() {
    $("#slide-container").height(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            w = $this.width() / 2.133;
        return w;
    });
}
slideHeight();


// Add span-wrappers around controls
$("a.controls").each(function() {
    $(this.firstChild).wrap("<span></span>");
});


// Position arrows vertically
function arrowPos() {
    $("a.controls > span").css("top", function() {
        var thisH = $(this).height(),
            parentH = $(this).parent().height(),
            thisTop = (parentH / 2) - (thisH / 2);
        return thisTop;
    });
}
arrowPos();


//Execute functions on resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    slideHeight();
    arrowPos();
});​
```

​There you go. :)

Comment: definitely better to avoid using javascript unless necessary though.

Comment: @samayres1992 There is no other way to perfectly center an element on a dynamic element.